# not getting primary email id in android project

Tags: android

Permission into ManiFest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

my xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
ImageView GoToNewActivity;
ImageView GoToNewActivity1;
TextView tvID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);

    String email = getEmiailID(this);
    if(email != null) {
        tvID.setText(email);
    } else {
        tvID.setText("Account haven't been found");
    }
 private String getEmiailID(Context context) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = getAccount(accountManager);
    if (account == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return account.name;
    }
}

private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        account = accounts[0];
    } else {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
    }

}
```

It is printing Account haven't been found, means not getting primary email. I have my primary email in my android device. Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this
**add this permission my friend**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**code for on create method**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    TextView tvID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    String email = getEmiailID(this);

    if (email != null) {
        tvID.setText(email);
    } else {
        tvID.setText("Account haven't been found");
    }
}
```

**create this method**

```
 private String getEmiailID(Context context) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = getAccount(accountManager);
    if (account == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return account.name;
    }
}

private Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return null;
    }
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        account = accounts[0];
    } else {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

Comment: @GauravMehra pass YourActivity.this as context my friend

Comment: its printing hello in fronted, not printing email

Comment: could you please correct my full code. please. i am beginner, so i am little bit confused

Comment: @GauravMehra check ans

Comment: @GauravMehra your code is correct just change few thing sthat i update in my ans and make sure you are giving run time permisiion of read contacts

Comment: @GauravMehra askmme in case of any query

Answer (score 0):

**[AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)**

> This class provides access to a centralized registry of the user's
>   online accounts.

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Make sure you enable **[Android's Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)** .

> Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if an app shares the
>   signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not
>   need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account.
>   On Android 5.1 and lower, all apps need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to
>   read information about any account.

```
 try 
   { 
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this); 
            if (accountManager == null) 
            {
             return ""; 
            }
            else
            {
                Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts(); 
                Pattern emailPatternOBJ = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
                for (Account account : accounts) 
                { 

                    if (emailPatternOBJ.matcher(account.name).matches()) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println("Primary_Mail_ID"+account.name); // Return Primary Email ID .
                        return account.name; 
                    } 
                } 
                return ""; 

           } 
           catch (SecurityException e) 
           { 
            // If app doesn't have GET_ACCOUNTS permission 
            return ""; 

           }

    }
```